# Find reflected angle off an arc

Tags: trigonometry

**Note**: Sorry if this question is elementary.

I am trying to find the reflected angle when a ball hits a 10 degree arc. I know I have to use trigonometry in some way, but I am having trouble grasping how to achieve this.

An illustration of what I want to achieve can be found below.

[image: angle of reflection off arc illustration]

Comment: You don't need trigonometry: just add the  angles of incidence and reflection. A ball coming in horizontally and meeting a surface at 10 degree angle will bounce back at 20 degree angle.

Comment: Is the arc circular? Are you familiar with the [Laws Of Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Laws_of_reflection)?

Comment: @pizza So the reflected angle = angle of incidence + the angle at the point that hits the arc?

Comment: Mark the center of your circle with some radius $a$.. Mark the inclination of incident ray. Reflected ray make double this angle. Now use your trig to find reflected ray equation.